# Simple Infinite Scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to build an infinite scroll for my website but I'm stuck :-/

I'd like to show some `scroll` items and then leave the rest to load once I begin scrolling down. How do I achieve this with my current script?

http://jsfiddle.net/sphhrrmo/

```js
$('.scroll').jscroll();
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pklauzinski/jscroll/master/jquery.jscroll.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">
    <h3>Page 1</h3>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
</div><div class="scroll">
    <h3>Page 1</h3>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
</div><div class="scroll">
    <h3>Page 1</h3>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
</div><div class="scroll">
    <h3>Page 1</h3>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
    <p>Content here...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var count = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()+$(window).height() > $(document).height() - 10){
       console.log( $(this).scrollTop()+$(window).height() + " " +$(document).height());

        $(".res").append("<br/>content " + count);
        count++;
    }
});`

`<div class="res">Content</div>`
http://jsfiddle.net/sphhrrmo/1/